# OpenShift: Notify each pod of cluster on deployment finished

Tags: service, deployment, openshift, hook

I have a service in OpenShift. The service consists of multiple pods. Each pod contains two container. Deployment strategy is "rolling update". I need to make specific container of every pod to know when current deployment is finished for all over the cluster.

Is file writing (from post deployment hook) to shared persistent volume a simplest correct way?

Answer (score 0):

A more reliable approach is to check number of available replicas though OpenShift API.

```
TOKEN="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"

curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt "https://openshift.default.svc.cluster.local/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/$YOUR_NAMESPACE/deployments/$YOUR_DEPLOYMENT" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq -r ".status.availableReplicas"
```

EDIT:

The API will also return desired replica counts as `.status.replicas`. So you can compare desired replica counts to available replica counts to decide if deployment is finished.

```
  "status": {
    "replicas": 2,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "availableReplicas": 1
  }
```

Comment: But in that way container need to know current pods count which is tunable externally.

Comment: The API not only returns current available pods count, but also desired pods counts.

Comment: And also I get  just `curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer`

Comment: And trying to query namespaces: `namespaces.extensions is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list namespaces.extensions at the cluster scope: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list all namespaces.extensions in the cluster`

Comment: Did you run this command inside a pod? Also, could you describe your deployment?  `oc describe deployment $YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME`

Comment: Yes, inside a pod. But I used wrong namespace, now I get `deployments.extensions "MY_DEPLOYMENT" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:MY_NAMESPACE:default" cannot get deployments.extensions in the namespace "MY_NAMESPACE": User "system:serviceaccount:MY_NAMESPACE:default" cannot get deployments.extensions in project "MY_NAMESPACE"`

Comment: I cannot make `oc describe deployment...` work. Where can I find correct `$YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME`?

Comment: You might be using `dc (deployment config)` instead of regular `deployment`. Could you run `oc get dc` and `oc get deployment` to check which one is in use?

Comment: Sorry for no feedback. I just used shared persistent volume because I needed also provide specific data to each pod. And then I finished my work on the feature.